# Flutter Close Multiple Modal Bottom Sheet programmatically

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have opened up a modal bottom sheet on pressed of a Raised button In the opened sheet, I have another icon that opens up another sheet but is it possible to close down both model bottom sheet when close button is pressed on the second bottom sheet.

I can able to close the first bottom sheet before opening the second one, but i have a back button in second model sheet when clicking on back button it need to go to first model bottom sheet.

```
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.pop(context);
   _openSecondSheet()
},
```

When clicking the close button on second bottom sheet I want to close both model bottom sheet.

Please help me.

Many thanks.

Comment: can you include minimal but full widget that will reproduce the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just pop twice.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Be very careful, that's not a great flow, and can crash the app if you pop too many times.